xhUsing Regex to find instances of a headr, then editing the lines below with some specifications
So I have this excerpt of the .msg file below. What I wish to do is for all the [sel xxx xxx] headers find them then read the lines below them. If any of the answers contain a (+3) or any (+x) then remove this from the message. Afterwards I want to compare each [sel xxx xxx] block and for the one with the highest (+x) I want to add another tag [clr 4] to it after the initial tags on the line but before the text. If there are two answers with equal (+x) then I wish to add [clr 4] to both lines.
[msg MSG_015_0_0 [Makoto]]
[s][bup 0 6 0 65535 1][f 4 10 65535 0 0][vp 8 0 0 0 65535 0]Dummy[n][f 1 3 65535][w][e]

[sel SEL_016_0_0 top]
[s]A(+3)[e]
[s]B[e]
[s]C(+3)[e]


[msg MSG_021_0_0 [Makoto]]
[s][bup 0 6 0 65535 1][f 4 10 65535 0 0][vp 8 0 0 0 65535 0]Sorry I had to ask something so[n]unreasonable... I appreciate you[n]going along with it, though.[n][f 1 3 65535][w][e]

[sel SEL_023_0_0 top]
[s]Fist! Of! Justice![e]
[s]Report him to the police.[e]
[s][f 0 8 2 1 2217]Try to reach out to her.(+3)[clr 27][e]

So the output should look like this:
[msg MSG_015_0_0 [Makoto]]
[s][bup 0 6 0 65535 1][f 4 10 65535 0 0][vp 8 0 0 0 65535 0]Dummy[n][f 1 3 65535][w][e]

[sel SEL_016_0_0 top]
[s][clr 4]A[e]
[s]B[e]
[s][clr 4]C[e]


[msg MSG_021_0_0 [Makoto]]
[s][bup 0 6 0 65535 1][f 4 10 65535 0 0][vp 8 0 0 0 65535 0]Sorry I had to ask something so[n]unreasonable... I appreciate you[n]going along with it, though.[n][f 1 3 65535][w][e]

[sel SEL_023_0_0 top]
[s]Fist! Of! Justice![e]
[s]Report him to the police.[e]
[s][f 0 8 2 1 2217][clr 4]Try to reach out to her.[clr 27][e]

I've been trying to write different pieces of code today but I'm very inexperienced with coding and I can never actually get it to run properly with the desired outcomes. I tried to solve it methodically by:

Identifying the [sel headers using regex.
Find any instances of (+x) and removing them
Prepending [clr 4] before the text of the line with maximum (+x).
Writing this back to an output file without any formatting changes (i.e. linebreaks stay the same, headers stay intact and it's mostly unchanged).

This is my attempt:
import re


def process_block(block):
    # Find all instances of `(+x)` and their positions in the block
    plus_x_matches = re.findall(r'\(\+(\d+)\)', block)
    if plus_x_matches:
        # Convert the found matches to integers and find the maximum
        max_x = max(map(int, plus_x_matches))
        # Replace all `(+x)` with an empty string
        block = re.sub(r'\(\+\d+\)', '', block)
        # Find the position where the maximum `(+x)` was found
        max_x_position = block.rfind(f'(+{max_x})')
        # If `(+x)` was found, insert `[col 4]` before the text
        if max_x_position != -1:
            # Insert `[col 4]` at the position of the max `(+x)`
            block = block[:max_x_position] + '[col 4]' + block[max_x_position:]
    return block


def main():
    # Read input file
    with open('input.msg', 'r') as infile:
        content = infile.read()

    # Split the content into blocks
    blocks = re.split(r'(\[sel .+? top\])', content)

    # Process each block
    result = []
    in_block = False
    current_block = ''
    for part in blocks:
        if part.startswith('[sel'):
            # If there's a previous block to process, do so
            if in_block:
                result.append(process_block(current_block))
                current_block = ''
            # Start a new block
            result.append(part)
            in_block = True
        elif in_block:
            # Append to the current block content
            current_block += part

    # Don't forget to process the last block
    if in_block:
        result.append(process_block(current_block))

    # Write output file
    with open('output.msg', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(''.join(result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Please post your best attempt. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

@Barmar I have added this now, sorry I forgot to include initially.

I took the codebase and added the logic to copy and replace in a new order.
A new pattern was built with several capture groups to take the content of each match and rearrange it into a new text with the requested replacement.
This code can run in terminal or jupyter notebook.
import re
content ="""
[msg MSG_015_0_0 [Makoto]]
[s][bup 0 6 0 65535 1][f 4 10 65535 0 0][vp 8 0 0 0 65535 0]Dummy[n][f 1 3 65535][w][e]

[sel SEL_016_0_0 top]
[s]A(+3)[e]
[s]B[e]
[s]C(+3)[e]


[msg MSG_021_0_0 [Makoto]]
[s][bup 0 6 0 65535 1][f 4 10 65535 0 0][vp 8 0 0 0 65535 0]Sorry I had to ask something so[n]unreasonable... I appreciate you[n]going along with it, though.[n][f 1 3 65535][w][e]

[sel SEL_023_0_0 top]
[s]Fist! Of! Justice![e]
[s]Report him to the police.[e]
[s][f 0 8 2 1 2217]Try to reach out to her.(+3)[clr 27][e]
"""

def process_block(block):
    # Find all instances of `(+x)` and their positions in the block
    plus_x_matches = re.findall(r'\(\+(\d+)\)', block)
    if plus_x_matches:
        # Convert the found matches to integers and find the maximum
        max_x = max(map(int, plus_x_matches))
        # Pattern to replace only lines with max_x value
        patter_find_replace = r'\[s\](\[.*?\])?(.*)(\(\+'+str(max_x)+r'\))(\[.*?\])?\[e\]'
        # important: this pattern have 4 groups, this is usefull to take and replace in a new order
        new_lines = []
        lines = block.split('\n')
        #separate block in lines and eval pattern to replace
        for l in lines :
            pattern = re.compile(patter_find_replace)
            matches = pattern.findall(l)
            if(len(matches)>0):
                item = matches[0]
                replaced = '[s]'+item[0]+'[col 4]'+item[1]+item[3]+'[e]'
                new_lines.append(replaced)
            else:
                new_lines.append(l)
        block = "\n".join(new_lines)
    return block

def main():
    # Split the content into blocks
    blocks = re.split(r'(\[sel .+? top\])', content)
    # Process each block
    result = []
    in_block = False
    current_block = ''
    for part in blocks:
        if part.startswith('[sel'):
            # If there's a previous block to process, do so
            if in_block:
                result.append(process_block(current_block))
                current_block = ''
            # Start a new block
            result.append(part)
            in_block = True
        elif in_block:
            # Append to the current block content
            current_block += part

    # Don't forget to process the last block
    if in_block:
        result.append(process_block(current_block))

    print('result:')
    for r in result:
        print(r)

main()


This still has some errors in the output but it's a lot better than what I initially had, thank you very much. I'll try and fix it to my specifications but this is amazing. Thank you very much!

You can tell me by comments what else needs to be fixed. I can think of a way to take only [sel] blocks and leave the [msg] blocks intact. I can spend 1 more hour on the problem.

If it has been helpful, do not forget to vote up.
